# Vertically align text of different font sizes in adjoining table cells

Tags: outlook, html-table, html-email, vertical-alignment, font-size

I'm trying to bottom-align text of different font sizes contained in adjacent table cells in an html email.

**code:**

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td style="font-size: 40px; font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#35C7E0; font-weight: bold; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height: 40px;" valign="bottom">2.</td>
         <td width="15" style="width: 15px; font-size: 18px; line-height: 40px;">&nbsp;</td>
         <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: #35C7E0; text-align: left; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height: 40px;"  valign="bottom">Product Demonstrations</td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

My problem is the text in the second cell (Product Demonstrations) appears lower than the "2" in the first cell in Outlook 2010 and 2013 but looks fine in Outlook 2011 and 2016. How can I fix it so all the text looks uniformly aligned at the bottom in all Outlook versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook 2007-10-13 dosnt understand valign=bottom on a text, so you need another table within your last td, and make that table valign=bottom. I also added some padding-bottom, to get it aligned with the "2".

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tr>
    <td>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size: 40px; font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#35C7E0; font-weight: bold; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height: 40px;" valign="bottom">2.</td>
                    <td width="15" style="width: 15px; font-size: 18px; line-height: 40px;">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td valign="bottom">
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: #35C7E0; text-align: left; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height: 100%; padding-bottom: 5px"> Lorem ipsum
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```